# regex match spaces before and after certain symbols

Tags: regex

How can the following regex be modified to look for spaces before and after certain symbols
`\s+(?=["!@#])`

This works on spaces before these symbols. How do I make it look for spaces after these symbols?

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ggZKYo/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please just put a positive lookbehind prior to your regex:

```
(?<=["!@#])\s+(?=["!@#])
```

[Demo on Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/CSZhS7/1)

Comment: Somehow, this only matches the first occurance. What are we missing?

Comment: @Norman thank you for the feedback, but I suppose it should match the multiple occurances as seen in the demo. BR.